# How do i put a DC motor on an arduino motor shield and use it

Tags: arduino, dc-motor, wiring

I'm building a robot using an Arduino UNO and the standard [Arduino Motor shield](http://arduino.cc/it/Main/ArduinoMotorShieldR3).

I have two 9-12V DC motors.  I'm open to the possibility of using servos, but I'm currently trying to use these motors.

How do I wire the motor to the microcontroller and program it to run? I've been looking for days on how to do this and returned unsuccessful.  I found the [Makezine blog post](http://blog.makezine.com/2012/01/10/new-in-the-maker-shed-arduino-motor-shield/) the most accessible resource, but I'm still not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/195) SparkFun tutorial shows you everything from soldering the motor leads to programming it from your Arduino IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Details are here: http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoMotorShieldR3

Comment: I need more basic questions answered, like if i solder the wires onto the motor, and if i do, how do i program it to my arduino... i checked it and couldnt understand earlier

Comment: Provide details of the motor.